# A Confusion about Raw query parameter

Tags: gmail-api

I am writing a simple migration tool in which I have to migrate  gmail mailboxes to some other email provider. I am confused about raw string returned from gmail api.

In Google document, it says:

- "raw": Returns the entire email message content in the raw field as a URL-safe base64 encoded string and the payload field is not used. This includes the identifiers, labels, metadata, MIME structure, and small body parts (typically less than 2KB).

So this means "raw" returns only small body parts less than 2kb and if the body parts are more than 2KB, there will be a problem. I have checked with some dummy emails containing email body(including inline attachments)  more than 2KB, and it still works. It still returns the complete body without any problem. Sorry,if  I missed something, please clear my confusion. If "raw" is working fine for all email body sizes , I will be using this approach in my project instead of "full" query parameter.

best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

messages.get(format=RAW) returns the entire email always.  That document: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get is incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Comment: so it does return external  attachments also ? sorry I have not tested with external attachments.

Comment: It returns the entire email as it was received over SMTP (incl. all attachments regardless of size).  What exactly do you mean by "external attachment"?

Comment: I believe there are two kinds of attachment, inline attachment and simple attachment. I referred simple attachment as external attachment.
thanks you cleared my doubts. :)

Comment: That matters for format=FULL, small attachments are stored inline with the parsed email.  Large attachments are ripped out and stored separately (since they are large and are often accessed separately).  For format=RAW the entire email (in RFC822 format, ready for SMTP, etc) is always present.